# Repeating query to MongoDB every second in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am running two Python scripts at the same time. The first one sends every 5 seconds a random number to my db. The one below connects to the DB and fetches every document from there.

The problem is that, when i run both of them at the same time on my console, i see data being added to the DB but the new data won't show up on the script below. To see the new data i have to close and run again it. What am i doing wrong?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
    import time
    import random
    from pprint import pprint

    #Step 1: Connect to MongoDB - Note: Change connection string as needed
    client = MongoClient(port=27017)

    arr = []

    db = client.one

    mycol = client["coll"]

    cursor = db.mycol.find()

    while True:
        for document in cursor:
            print(document['num'])
```

Comment: "Repeating the query every second" is probably not what you *really* want here. Instead read [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) or in older releases basically look for "tailing the oplog" for that that new feature gives a more modern "contained" access to. That's a lot more durable than scheduling repeated query operations just to *"see new items"*, which is what your intent appears to be from the content of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the 'db.mycol.find()' into the loop and also you are  missing the 'time.sleep(5)' in the loop.

Comment: I moved that line into my While loop but it still seems not to work, think my Whole code is wrong and i should try to think it in completely another way